# Android ActionBarSherlock style selected action item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have a `ViewPager` AND each page displays a photo. I show a split `ActionBar` with like/dislike action that are used so user can vote 'like' the photo or 'dislike' it.

I successfully implemented the vote feature for each photo.

**Problem**:

How do I style the selected vote for each photo? In other words, how can I mange the `MenuItem` icon based on the current state of the photo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `boolean` to detect when a photo is liked, then call `setIcon` on your `MenuItem`.

```
final MenuItem liked = YOUR_MENU.findItem(THE_LIKED_ACTION_ID);
    if (isLiked()) {
        liked.setIcon(YOUR_LIKED_DRAWABLE);
    } else {
        liked.setIcon(YOUR_DEFAULT_LIKED_DRAWABLE);
    }

mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thinking out loud... since it's a ViewPager with a set amount of pages, I should use an array of boolean? I will also need invalidateOptionsMenu()?

Comment: A made an edit showing how to call `invalidateOptionsMenu` with your `ViewPager` because you will need to call that. As far as the array goes, I suppose you could do that if that's what you wanted. Also, you should consider removing the "dislike" action. It's repetitive. If a user doesn't like a photo, then they won't press the "like" button.

Comment: on the side note: you know how the splitABS bottom bar has a horizontal separator on top of (above) the action buttons. Do you know how I can get rid of that separator?